# Reconstruction of a SVN repo

Tags: svn

Is it possible to recreate a SVN repository with history using the .svn folder from the working directory?

I found out someone mistakenly deleted the repository and the backup is numerous revisions old.

Looked in the "Svn RedBook" and it did not help. Google was not useful either.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to recreate a SVN repository with history using the .svn folder from the working directory?

No, working copy does not have any revision history. It only have the base version of your data (the revision you checked out or updated the working copy to stored in the pristine area in the `.svn` directory), and a working tree (the files you actually see and work on in the working copy).

Contents of the working copy can only help you restore the snapshot of the repository from which you checked the working copy. But not the actual commits or history of changes.

So if you don't have more recent backups, your last call is as follows:

1. Restore the backup,
2. Check out a working copy from this restored repository,
3. Copy the data from your previous working copy (the one with more recent data) into a new working copy (all data *excluding the `.svn` directory).
4. Examine the changes and commit.

This way you at least restore the latest available snapshot of your data.